Hibernate Exception While Saving Arena Data (No row with the given identifier exists)
this is my first time integrating Hibernate ORM into my project, and I'm having some trouble trying to debug the org.hibernate.UnresolvableObjectException: No row with the given identifier exists exception, and I'm not entirely sure if it's because I annotated my class incorrectly, or if I am doing something entirely wrong.
[09:19:38 INFO]: [STDOUT] [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger] Hibernate: select am1_0.id,a1_0.arena_manager_id,a1_0.name,a1_0.id,a1_0.car_part_locations,a1_0.corners,a1_0.schematic,a1_0.spawn,a1_0.truck from arena_manager am1_0 left join arena a1_0 on am1_0.id=a1_0.arena_manager_id where am1_0.id=?
[09:19:38 ERROR]: [Murder Run] Exception while handling click event in inventory 'Create or modify a lobby', slot=16, item=GREEN_WOOL
org.hibernate.UnresolvableObjectException: No row with the given identifier exists: [io.github.pulsebeat02.murderrun.game.arena.ArenaManager#5]
    at org.hibernate.UnresolvableObjectException.throwIfNull(UnresolvableObjectException.java:49) ~[?:?]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultRefreshEventListener.refresh(DefaultRefreshEventListener.java:201) ~[?:?]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultRefreshEventListener.refresh(DefaultRefreshEventListener.java:184) ~[?:?]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultRefreshEventListener.onRefresh(DefaultRefreshEventListener.java:109) ~[?:?]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultRefreshEventListener.onRefresh(DefaultRefreshEventListener.java:55) ~[?:?]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127) ~[?:?]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireRefresh(SessionImpl.java:1218) ~[?:?]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.refresh(SessionImpl.java:1181) ~[?:?]
    at MurderRun-1.21.1-v1.0.0-all-1729700029542.jar/io.github.pulsebeat02.murderrun.data.hibernate.controllers.AbstractController.serialize(AbstractController.java:51) ~[MurderRun-1.21.1-v1.0.0-all-1729700029542.jar:?]
    at MurderRun-1.21.1-v1.0.0-all-1729700029542.jar/io.github.pulsebeat02.murderrun.MurderRun.updatePluginData(MurderRun.java:158) ~[MurderRun-1.21.1-v1.0.0-all-1729700029542.jar:?]
    at MurderRun-1.21.1-v1.0.0-all-1729700029542.jar/io.github.pulsebeat02.murderrun.gui.lobby.LobbyModificationGui.createNewLobby(LobbyModificationGui.java:191) ~[MurderRun-1.21.1-v1.0.0-all-1729700029542.jar:?]
    at com.github.stefvanschie.inventoryframework.gui.GuiItem.callAction(GuiItem.java:178) ~[?:?]
    at com.github.stefvanschie.inventoryframework.pane.PatternPane.click(PatternPane.java:216) ~[?:?]
    at com.github.stefvanschie.inventoryframework.gui.InventoryComponent.click(InventoryComponent.java:205) ~[?:?]
    at com.github.stefvanschie.inventoryframework.gui.type.ChestGui.click(ChestGui.java:161) ~[?:?]
    at com.github.stefvanschie.inventoryframework.gui.GuiListener.onInventoryClick(GuiListener.java:84) ~[?:?]
    at com.destroystokyo.paper.event.executor.asm.generated.GeneratedEventExecutor85.execute(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.EventExecutor$2.execute(EventExecutor.java:77) ~[paper-mojangapi-1.21.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at co.aikar.timings.TimedEventExecutor.execute(TimedEventExecutor.java:80) ~[paper-mojangapi-1.21.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.21.1-128-d348cb8]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:70) ~[paper-mojangapi-1.21.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at io.papermc.paper.plugin.manager.PaperEventManager.callEvent(PaperEventManager.java:54) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-128-d348cb8]
    at io.papermc.paper.plugin.manager.PaperPluginManagerImpl.callEvent(PaperPluginManagerImpl.java:131) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-128-d348cb8]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:628) ~[paper-mojangapi-1.21.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.server.network.ServerGamePacketListenerImpl.handleContainerClick(ServerGamePacketListenerImpl.java:3224) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-128-d348cb8]
    at net.minecraft.network.protocol.game.ServerboundContainerClickPacket.handle(ServerboundContainerClickPacket.java:69) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-128-d348cb8]
    at net.minecraft.network.protocol.game.ServerboundContainerClickPacket.handle(ServerboundContainerClickPacket.java:33) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-128-d348cb8]
    at net.minecraft.network.protocol.PacketUtils.lambda$ensureRunningOnSameThread$0(PacketUtils.java:56) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-128-d348cb8]
    at net.minecraft.server.TickTask.run(TickTask.java:18) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-128-d348cb8]
    at net.minecraft.util.thread.BlockableEventLoop.doRunTask(BlockableEventLoop.java:151) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-128-d348cb8]
    at net.minecraft.util.thread.ReentrantBlockableEventLoop.doRunTask(ReentrantBlockableEventLoop.java:24) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-128-d348cb8]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.doRunTask(MinecraftServer.java:1535) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-128-d348cb8]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.doRunTask(MinecraftServer.java:201) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-128-d348cb8]
    at net.minecraft.util.thread.BlockableEventLoop.pollTask(BlockableEventLoop.java:125) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-128-d348cb8]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.pollTaskInternal(MinecraftServer.java:1512) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-128-d348cb8]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.pollTask(MinecraftServer.java:1505) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-128-d348cb8]
    at net.minecraft.util.thread.BlockableEventLoop.managedBlock(BlockableEventLoop.java:135) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-128-d348cb8]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.managedBlock(MinecraftServer.java:1464) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-128-d348cb8]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.waitUntilNextTick(MinecraftServer.java:1471) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-128-d348cb8]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.runServer(MinecraftServer.java:1316) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-128-d348cb8]
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$spin$0(MinecraftServer.java:329) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-128-d348cb8]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[?:?]

For context, here is my ArenaManager.java
package io.github.pulsebeat02.murderrun.game.arena;

import io.github.pulsebeat02.murderrun.data.hibernate.HibernateIdentifiers;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serial;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.KeyFor;
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.Nullable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "arena_manager")
public final class ArenaManager implements Serializable {

  @Serial
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -2378194945450834205L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id = HibernateIdentifiers.ARENA_MANAGER_ID;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @MapKeyColumn(name = "name")
  @JoinColumn(name = "arena_manager_id")
  @Column(name = "arena")
  private final Map<String, Arena> arenas;

  public ArenaManager() {
    this.arenas = new HashMap<>();
  }

  public void addArena(
    final String name,
    final Location[] corners,
    final Location[] itemLocations,
    final Location spawn,
    final Location truck
  ) {
    final ArenaSchematic schematic = ArenaSchematic.copyAndCreateSchematic(name, corners);
    final Arena arena = new Arena(schematic, name, corners, itemLocations, spawn, truck);
    this.arenas.put(name, arena);
  }

  public @Nullable Arena getArena(final String name) {
    return this.arenas.get(name);
  }

  public void removeArena(final String name) {
    this.arenas.remove(name);
  }

  public Map<String, Arena> getArenas() {
    return this.arenas;
  }

  public Set<@KeyFor("this.arenas") String> getArenaNames() {
    return this.arenas.keySet();
  }
}

Arena.java
package io.github.pulsebeat02.murderrun.game.arena;

import io.github.pulsebeat02.murderrun.data.hibernate.HibernateIdentifiers;
import io.github.pulsebeat02.murderrun.data.hibernate.converters.LocationConverter;
import io.github.pulsebeat02.murderrun.utils.RandomUtils;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Convert;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import java.io.Serial;
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.util.BoundingBox;

@Entity
@Table(name = "arena")
public final class Arena implements Serializable {

  @Serial
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -6251041532325023867L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id = HibernateIdentifiers.ARENA_ID;

  @Column(name = "schematic")
  private final ArenaSchematic schematic;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private final String name;

  @Convert(converter = LocationConverter.class)
  @Column(name = "corners")
  private final Location[] corners;

  @Convert(converter = LocationConverter.class)
  @Column(name = "car_part_locations")
  private final Location[] carPartLocations;

  @Convert(converter = LocationConverter.class)
  @Column(name = "spawn")
  private final Location spawn;

  @Convert(converter = LocationConverter.class)
  @Column(name = "truck")
  private final Location truck;

  public Arena(
    final ArenaSchematic schematic,
    final String name,
    final Location[] corners,
    final Location[] carPartLocations,
    final Location spawn,
    final Location truck
  ) {
    this.schematic = schematic;
    this.name = name;
    this.corners = corners;
    this.carPartLocations = carPartLocations;
    this.spawn = spawn;
    this.truck = truck;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  public Location getFirstCorner() {
    return this.corners[0];
  }

  public Location getSecondCorner() {
    return this.corners[1];
  }

  public Location getSpawn() {
    return this.spawn;
  }

  public Location getTruck() {
    return this.truck;
  }

  public Location[] getCorners() {
    return this.corners;
  }

  public ArenaSchematic getSchematic() {
    return this.schematic;
  }

  public BoundingBox createBox() {
    return BoundingBox.of(this.corners[0], this.corners[1]);
  }

  public Location[] getCarPartLocations() {
    return this.carPartLocations;
  }

  public Location getRandomItemLocation() {
    final int length = this.carPartLocations.length;
    if (length == 0) {
      return this.spawn;
    }

    final int index = RandomUtils.generateInt(length);
    final Location location = this.carPartLocations[index];
    final Location drop = location.clone();
    drop.add(0, 1.5, 0);

    return drop;
  }
}

ArenaSchematic.java
package io.github.pulsebeat02.murderrun.game.arena;

import static java.util.Objects.requireNonNull;

import com.sk89q.worldedit.EditSession;
import com.sk89q.worldedit.WorldEdit;
import com.sk89q.worldedit.WorldEditException;
import com.sk89q.worldedit.bukkit.BukkitAdapter;
import com.sk89q.worldedit.extent.clipboard.BlockArrayClipboard;
import com.sk89q.worldedit.extent.clipboard.Clipboard;
import com.sk89q.worldedit.extent.clipboard.io.BuiltInClipboardFormat;
import com.sk89q.worldedit.extent.clipboard.io.ClipboardWriter;
import com.sk89q.worldedit.function.operation.ForwardExtentCopy;
import com.sk89q.worldedit.function.operation.Operations;
import com.sk89q.worldedit.math.BlockVector3;
import com.sk89q.worldedit.regions.CuboidRegion;
import io.github.pulsebeat02.murderrun.data.hibernate.converters.BlockVectorConverter;
import io.github.pulsebeat02.murderrun.data.hibernate.converters.PathConverter;
import io.github.pulsebeat02.murderrun.utils.IOUtils;
import it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.io.FastBufferedOutputStream;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Convert;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Serial;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.World;

public final class ArenaSchematic implements Serializable {

  @Serial
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 4953428050756665476L;

  @Convert(converter = PathConverter.class)
  @Column(name = "schematic_path")
  private final Path schematicPath;

  @Convert(converter = BlockVectorConverter.class)
  @Column(name = "origin")
  private final BlockVector3 origin;

  public ArenaSchematic(final Path schematicPath, final BlockVector3 origin) {
    this.schematicPath = schematicPath;
    this.origin = origin;
  }

  public static ArenaSchematic copyAndCreateSchematic(final String name, final Location[] corners) {
    try {
      final Clipboard clipboard = performForwardExtentCopy(corners);
      final Path path = performSchematicWrite(clipboard, name);
      final BlockVector3 origin = clipboard.getOrigin();
      return new ArenaSchematic(path, origin);
    } catch (final WorldEditException | IOException e) {
      throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
  }

  private static Clipboard performForwardExtentCopy(final Location[] corners) throws WorldEditException {
    final CuboidRegion region = createRegion(corners);
    final BlockArrayClipboard clipboard = new BlockArrayClipboard(region);
    final com.sk89q.worldedit.world.World world = region.getWorld();
    final WorldEdit instance = WorldEdit.getInstance();
    try (final EditSession session = instance.newEditSession(world)) {
      final BlockVector3 min = region.getMinimumPoint();
      final ForwardExtentCopy forwardExtentCopy = new ForwardExtentCopy(session, region, clipboard, min);
      forwardExtentCopy.setCopyingEntities(true);
      Operations.complete(forwardExtentCopy);
      return clipboard;
    }
  }

  private static Path performSchematicWrite(final Clipboard clipboard, final String name) throws IOException {
    final Path data = IOUtils.getPluginDataFolderPath();
    final Path parent = data.resolve("schematics");
    IOUtils.createFolder(parent);

    final Path file = parent.resolve(name);
    final BuiltInClipboardFormat format = BuiltInClipboardFormat.SPONGE_V3_SCHEMATIC;
    try (
      final OutputStream stream = Files.newOutputStream(file);
      final OutputStream fast = new FastBufferedOutputStream(stream);
      final ClipboardWriter writer = format.getWriter(fast)
    ) {
      writer.write(clipboard);
    }

    return file;
  }

  private static CuboidRegion createRegion(final Location[] corners) {
    final Location first = corners[0];
    final Location second = corners[1];
    final World world = requireNonNull(first.getWorld());
    final BlockVector3 firstCorner = BukkitAdapter.asBlockVector(first);
    final BlockVector3 secondCorner = BukkitAdapter.asBlockVector(second);
    final com.sk89q.worldedit.world.World instance = BukkitAdapter.adapt(world);
    return new CuboidRegion(instance, firstCorner, secondCorner);
  }

  public Path getSchematicPath() {
    return this.schematicPath;
  }

  public BlockVector3 getOrigin() {
    return this.origin;
  }
}

I am trying to import these entities into my H2 embedded server database. I have an abstract Controller class that controls my manager classes such as ArenaManager.
package io.github.pulsebeat02.murderrun.data.hibernate.controllers;

import static java.util.Objects.*;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

public abstract class AbstractController<T> implements Controller<T> {

  private final SessionFactory factory;
  private final Object id;

  public AbstractController(final SessionFactory factory, final Object id) {
    this.factory = factory;
    this.id = id;
  }

  @Override
  public T deserialize() {
    try (final Session session = this.factory.openSession()) {
      final Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
      final Class<T> clazz = this.getGenericClass();
      final T manager = session.get(clazz, this.id);
      final T defaultEntity = requireNonNull(this.createDefaultEntity());
      final T returnEntity = requireNonNullElse(manager, defaultEntity);
      transaction.commit();
      return returnEntity;
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
  }

  public abstract T createDefaultEntity();

  @Override
  public void shutdown() {
    if (this.factory.isOpen()) {
      this.factory.close();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void serialize(final T data) {
    if (data == null) {
      return;
    }

    try (final Session session = this.factory.openSession()) {
      final Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
      session.merge(data); // error occurs here
      transaction.commit();
    }
  }
}

I use pre-set ID's because I want to set the identifier for each of my managers, such as my ArenaManager.
package io.github.pulsebeat02.murderrun.data.hibernate;

public interface HibernateIdentifiers {
  Long LOBBY_ID = 1L;
  Long ARENA_ID = 2L;
  Long PLAYER_STATISTICS_ID = 3L;
  Long LOBBY_MANAGER_ID = 4L;
  Long ARENA_MANAGER_ID = 5L;
  Long STATISTICS_MANAGER_ID = 6L;
}

I am giving my users to store data in either JSON or through a database like H2, and the JSON saving format works, but I am trying to figure out how to do it through databases via Hibernate. I don't want to create a new set of Arena data abstractions for databases only, and I want to use my current manager and annotate the Map correctly so it corresponds with the rows and columns of my H2 database.
When I try to update/save my data into the database after my ArenaManager instance has been changed or modified by the user (usually by new or removed entries in the underlying Map), I end up with the exception above.
I've tried doing some further research onto more StackOverflow threads, forums, and asked in various Discord's, but I had no luck because I'm not sure what could be the source of this error. I've seen many other threads with this same issue, but I can't seem to really track the source or cause from the stack-trace because of my lack of experience. It would be greatly appreciated if someone could point me into the right direction. Thank you.

Please add your code into text of the question. External links are not appreciated.

@talexmovedtoCodidact I changed my post and removed the external links to include the code into the text of the question, does this look good?

Try this in your entities:
private Long id;

instead of
private Long id = HibernateIdentifiers.ARENA_ID;

